# Events for Inertial Scrolling on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ipad, events, safari, scroll

I am currently using overflow:scroll on a web page optimized for the iPad, and it works great.  I began running into trouble with touch events on the items in the scrolling div, because it was interpreting the scrolling swipes as touches.  Since there is no scroll complete event, and the scroll event fires each time you scroll, I tried detecting the scroll event and setting a timer to disable the touch event temporarily.  However, I have discovered that the scroll event only fires each time the user initiates a scroll, which is rarely with inertial scrolling.

Is there a constantly firing scroll event or some other way to detect that scrolling is currently happening?

This is only a problem with inertial scrolling on Mobile Safari, because when you move your mouse on OS X, inertial scrolling automatically stops, so to initiate the click event, you would generally need to move the mouse, thus avoiding a conflict.  You also don't have the dual use input of touch for scrolling and touch for tapping.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", ScrollStart, false);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll, false);
    function ScrollStart() {
        //start of scroll event for iOS
    }
    function Scroll() {
        //end of scroll event for iOS
        //and
        //start/end of scroll event for other browsers
    }   
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: I believe he is referring to the momentum scrolling period which isn't handled by either 'touchmove' or 'scroll' events.

Comment: just having spent a day verifying this on iOS7 with a div set to overflow:scroll - safari will fire scroll events in two cases: **1) the user touches and then moves their touch to start a scroll** - it looks like the scroll event fires as much as the touchmove event in this case **2) the user has initiated a "flick" style scroll** - safari will only fire a scroll event once the scrolling comes to rest (including the bottom bounce)

Comment: since i also looked into Chrome on Android 4.4 - Chrome will actually fire scroll events while the scroll is occurring (even with inertia) and will fire a single touchmove event at the beginning of the scroll. Safari, however, will fire **both** scroll and touchmove events while the finger is held down and the div is scrolled.

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to account for the momentum of the scroll? If I use the above, the end of scroll fires even when the scrolling is slowing down and has not stopped completely.