# jQuery scrollstop and webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: jquery, ios, css, webkit

I discovered an issue when using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` and the jQuery event `scrollstop` where the `scrollstop` event will be fired twice, once when the element has truly stopped scrolling (which is the behavior desired) but also when a user has stopped scrolling but inertia is still scrolling the element (which is not desired) on an iOS device. Is there a workaround to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Came across this solution. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830701/events-for-inertial-scrolling-on-mobile-safari